# How to read pdf table in Flutter

Tags: flutter, pdf, tabula, tabula-py

In python, tabula-py can be used to extract tables from a pdf file. Is there a way to do the same within a flutter app?

Comment: If your Flutter app is going to run only on Android devices then include tabula-java in your Android project and access the library through method channel. This can be one of the solutions. If you find anything better than this then please comment.

Comment: @KalpeshKundanani I tried importing tabula-java in android, but seems like it needs awt, which is not found in the android jvm

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at the same problem for one of my side projects. The solution I plan is - to have a backend API developed with python + Django REST / gRPC, upload the file from flutter app into the backend, read tables in backend using tabula and return needed information back to flutter app through API. I feel this will be more cleaner. Let me know if you find any other shortcut as well :-).